# A conditional probability issue

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**Question**
:Is the following statement right or wrong?

If $P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid B^c)\rightarrow \:A$ and $B$  :aren't collectively exhaustive events.

Where $A$ and $B$ are independent and  $P(A)>0$ , $P(B)<1$

**What I did**

I started supposing that the statement is false, so

if $A\cup B=Ω,\:\:B^c=A$ in that case

$P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid B^c)$

$P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid A)$ Because $B^c=A$

$P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid A)$

$P(A)=\frac{P(A\cap A)}{P(A)}$ $A$ and $B$ are independent

$P(A)=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}$

$P(A\mid B)=1$ or $P(A)=1$

My question is does this result makes sense, implies that is false?
Can $P(A)=1$ be right? because that would imply that $P(A)=P(Ω)$ right?

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are independent then $P(A)=P(A|B)=P(A|B^c)$

Comment: @Masacroso thanks for commenting, yes I'm aware of that, and I'm taking that as true, my question is given that, that is true, does that means that A and B are or not mutually exhaustive?

Comment: @AdamRubinson the question is if they are collectively exhaustive events. I put mutually exhaustive events. Now I change mutually for collective https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectively_exhaustive_events

Comment: Oh, I assumed you meant mutually exclusive. I've not heard the term "collectively exhaustive" before. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If sets $\ A,\ B\ $ are [collectively exhaustive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectively_exhaustive_events) then $P(A \cup B) =  1.$

I don't see why you can't have $\ P(A)=1,\ B\subset A,\ $ and $P(B) = 0.$ This would fulfil all the requirements, right?

We would need $\ P(B)=0\ $ though, as if $\ P(A)=1\ $ and $\ P(B) > 0,\ $ then $P(B\vert A)>0=P(B\vert A^c),\ $ contradicting independence.

However, I think if we adjust the restriction on event $A$ to $\ P(A)<1,\ $ then we would have:

$(1-P(B))(1-P(A))>0 \implies P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B) < 1  $

$$\overset{\mbox{(indep)}}{\implies} P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) < 1 $$

$$\implies P(A\cup B) < 1, $$

meaning $A$ and $B$ are not collectively exhaustive.